# Get orders by payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, payment-methods

I am developing a cron supposed to capture all the recent orders from a specific payment method, but I currently have a problem getting all the orders from a specific payment method.

I thought that the payment method would be in the `sales_flat_order` table, but it isn't, so I can not use something like :

```
$ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('payment_method', $paymentMethod);
```

**How can I filter all the orders and only get the one with a certain payment method ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this using joining the collections:

```
$table_prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
$order_table = $table_prefix.'sales_flat_order';
$on_condition = "main_table.parent_id = $order_table.entity_id";

$orderCollection =  Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('method',"PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME");    // for e.g checkmo

$orderCollection ->getSelect()->join($order_table,$on_condition);

foreach($orderCollection as $order):
 echo '<br/>ORDER # : '.$order->getIncrementId();
endforeach;
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 $ordersByPaymentCheckMo = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_payment_collection')            
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('method',"checkmo");

foreach($ordersByPaymentCheckMo as $orderByPayment):
      $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderByPayment->getParentId());
     echo '<br/>ORDER # : '.$order->getIncrementId();
endforeach;
```

Hope this work for you.